# How to find if an array is subset of another array?

Tags: lua, moonscript

In Python we can use set or itertools to find the subset of one list of another list, how do we do the same in Lua ?

```
a = {1,2,3}
b = {2,3}
```

How do i check that b is a subset of a ?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets can be implemented in Lua using tables as look-ups for membership testing ([as done in Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.5.html)). The keys in the table are the elements of the set and the values are either `true` if the element belongs to the set or `nil` otherwise.

```
a = {[1]=true, [2]=true, [3]=true}
b = {[2]=true, [3]=true}

-- Or create a constructor
function set(list)
   local t = {}
   for _, item in pairs(list) do
       t[item] = true
   end
   return t
end

a = set{1, 2, 3}
b = set{2, 3}
```

Writing set operations is straightforward in this form as well ([as here](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.2.html)).

```
function subset(a, b)
   for el, _ in pairs(a) do
      if not b[el] then
         return false
      end
    end
   return true
end

print(subset(b, a)) -- true
print(subset(set{2, 1}, set{2, 2, 3, 1})) -- true

a[1] = nil -- remove 1 from a
print(subset(a, b)) -- true
```

If `a` and `b` must remain in array form then subset can be implemented like so:

```
function arraysubset(a, b)
   local s = set(b)
   for _, el in pairs(a) -- changed to iterate over values of the table
      if not s[el] then
         return false
      end
   end
   return true
end
```